# Click on text link selenium rc

Tags: text, selenium, hyperlink, click, selenium-rc

I am using selenium rc in eclipse with testNG. I need to click on text link. Here is the source code of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
dmenu = new dTree('dmenu');
dmenu.add(0,-1,'');
dmenu.add(1,0,'<b>World</b>','','');
...
```

In development tools the code looks like this:

```
  <link type="text/css" href="../css/dtree.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
   <script src="../script/dtree.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <div class="dtree">
      <script type="text/javascript"> dmenu = new dTree('dmenu'); dmenu.add(0,-1,''); dmenu.add(1,0,'<b>World</b>','',''); ................
       <div class="dtree">
        <div id="ddmenu0" class="clip" style="display:block;">
         <div class="dTreeNode">
           <a class="node" href="javascript: dmenu.o(1);">
             <b>World</b>
           </a>
```

I try someting like this `selenium.click("xpath=//b[contains( text(),'World')]");`, but get the error elememt not found. Could anybody help?

Comment: try     `selenium.click("css=b");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on the link using its class as xpath. i.e.,

```
selenium.click("class=node");
```

Try it once.